# sql filter by condition but result show everything

Tags: mysql, sql

Having this table

```
trans_date | settle_date | type
2022-06-08 | 2022-06-09  |  In
2022-06-08 | 2022-06-09  |  In
2022-06-08 |             |  Out
2022-06-09 |             |  Out
```

I want to only select:

1. If type is In, use settle_date
2. If type is Out, use trans_date

I am doing this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tx 
    WHERE DATE(CASE WHEN tx.type= 'IN' 
                    THEN tx.settle_date 
                    ELSE tx.trans_date END) <= '2022-06-08' .
       OR DATE(CASE WHEN tx.type = 'IN' 
                    THEN tx.settle_date 
                    ELSE tx.trans_date END) <= '2022-06-09'
```

but everything is select out, I expected the last row to be excluded.

I want IN to use <= 2022-06-09 and OUT to use <= 2022-06-08

Comment: Why should the last row be excluded? Since type = 'out', it uses the `trans_date`. `trans_data <= '2022-06-09'` is true.

Comment: Maybe you didn't mean to have both `<= 2022-06-08` and `<= 2022-06-09` conditions?

Comment: @Barmar I want IN to use <= 2022-06-09  and OUT to use <= 2022-06-08

Comment: The `CASE` expressions only select which column to test, not which date to compare with.

Comment: Why didn't you put those date conditions where you wrote "only select"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only choosing the column in the `CASE` expression, not the dates to compare with. Then you're selecting a row if that column is less than either of the dates, because of the `OR` condition.

Put the whole comparison in the `CASE` expression, not just the column name.

```
SELECT *
FROM tx
WHERE CASE tx.type
    WHEN 'IN' THEN tx.settle_date <= '2022-06-09'
    ELSE tx.trans_date <= '2022-06-08'
END
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tVARLBEPu8wCjGvbRJEAHd/0)

Answer (score 0):

You said *"..I expected the last row to be excluded."*, which I assume is your expected result.. so could you perhaps mean something like this:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN tx.type= 'In' 
             AND tx.settle_date <= '2022-06-09' 
                    THEN tx.settle_date 
            WHEN tx.type= 'Out' 
             AND tx.trans_date <= '2022-06-08' 
                    THEN tx.trans_date END AS f_date
FROM tx
HAVING f_date IS NOT NULL
```

Instead of doing `WHERE`, you probably want to do it in `SELECT` then filter the result afterward.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=07e6d4aa8dffbdb13efdd07495d7701c)